# GitHub actions not building a class library that a project is dependent on

Tags: asp.net-core, github-actions, cicd

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project. I set up CI/CD with Github actions and deployment to Azure and it worked fine.

Recently, I abstracted models from the API project into a class library that is shared across the Web API, mobile app (.NET MAUI) and Blazor website. Hence I added the class library to the API project as follows:

[image]

And building the application locally, it works.

But Github actions fails (Relevant logs):

```
2023-12-15T14:58:02.6383754Z ##[group]Run dotnet build --configuration Release
2023-12-15T14:58:02.6384309Z [36;1mdotnet build --configuration Release[0m
2023-12-15T14:58:02.6437277Z shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
2023-12-15T14:58:02.6437726Z env:
2023-12-15T14:58:02.6437939Z   AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: ApiMedbase
2023-12-15T14:58:02.6438268Z   AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: .
2023-12-15T14:58:02.6438545Z   DOTNET_VERSION: 7.0.x
2023-12-15T14:58:02.6438925Z   DOTNET_ROOT: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet
2023-12-15T14:58:02.6439348Z ##[endgroup]
2023-12-15T14:58:03.3054427Z MSBuild version 17.7.4+3ebbd7c49 for .NET
2023-12-15T14:58:03.8209836Z C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\7.0.404\NuGet.targets(400,5): error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\MedbaseWebApi\MedbaseLibrary\MedbaseLibrary.csproj" was not found. [D:\a\MedbaseWebApi\MedbaseWebApi\MedbaseApi.sln]
2023-12-15T14:58:07.1691930Z 
2023-12-15T14:58:07.1692539Z Build FAILED.
2023-12-15T14:58:07.1694501Z 
2023-12-15T14:58:07.1696860Z C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\7.0.404\NuGet.targets(400,5): error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\MedbaseWebApi\MedbaseLibrary\MedbaseLibrary.csproj" was not found. [D:\a\MedbaseWebApi\MedbaseWebApi\MedbaseApi.sln]
2023-12-15T14:58:07.1699862Z     0 Warning(s)
2023-12-15T14:58:07.1712309Z     1 Error(s)
2023-12-15T14:58:07.1716297Z 
2023-12-15T14:58:07.1716544Z Time Elapsed 00:00:03.76
2023-12-15T14:58:07.3140822Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It's obvious to me that I haven't hooked up the class library project to be built in the YAML file but I have been scouring the internet looking for how to do it and I am stumped. Please help me.

Below is the GitHub actions YAML file contents

```
name: Build and deploy ASP.NET Core app to an Azure Web App

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: ApiMedbase    # set this to the name of your Azure Web App
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET_VERSION: '7.0.x'                 # set this to the .NET Core version to use

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: 'true'

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: Set up dependency caching for faster builds
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.nuget/packages
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/packages.lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

EDIT: Logs from adding the library as a submodule.

```
2023-12-15T15:13:35.3961738Z ##[group]Fetching submodules
2023-12-15T15:13:35.3968942Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" submodule sync
2023-12-15T15:13:35.7835171Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --depth=1
2023-12-15T15:13:36.1660002Z Submodule 'MedbaseLibrary' (https://github.com/tanakamawere/MedbaseLibrary) registered for path 'MedbaseLibrary'
2023-12-15T15:13:36.8254174Z Cloning into 'D:/a/MedbaseWebApi/MedbaseWebApi/MedbaseLibrary'...
2023-12-15T15:13:36.8904519Z Submodule path 'MedbaseLibrary': checked out '3448be6ad145eda29cceadd2e0e726d2361641be'
2023-12-15T15:13:36.9062948Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" submodule foreach "git config --local gc.auto 0"
2023-12-15T15:13:37.3090097Z Entering 'MedbaseLibrary'
2023-12-15T15:13:37.3452908Z ##[endgroup]
2023-12-15T15:13:37.3453392Z ##[group]Persisting credentials for submodules
2023-12-15T15:13:37.3463574Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" submodule foreach --recursive "sh -c \"git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'url\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.insteadOf' && git config --local --unset-all 'url.https://github.com/.insteadOf' || :\""
2023-12-15T15:13:37.7313465Z Entering 'MedbaseLibrary'
2023-12-15T15:13:37.8050688Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" submodule foreach "sh -c \"git config --local 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' 'AUTHORIZATION: basic ***' && git config --local --show-origin --name-only --get-regexp remote.origin.url\""
2023-12-15T15:13:38.1976844Z Entering 'MedbaseLibrary'
2023-12-15T15:13:38.2568078Z file:D:/a/MedbaseWebApi/MedbaseWebApi/.git/modules/MedbaseLibrary/config   remote.origin.url
2023-12-15T15:13:38.2668364Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" submodule foreach "git config --local --add 'url.https://github.com/.insteadOf' 'git@github.com:'"
2023-12-15T15:13:38.6480169Z Entering 'MedbaseLibrary'
2023-12-15T15:13:38.6812291Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" submodule foreach "git config --local --add 'url.https://github.com/.insteadOf' 'org-63114898@github.com:'"
2023-12-15T15:13:39.0560111Z Entering 'MedbaseLibrary'
2023-12-15T15:13:39.0902393Z ##[endgroup]
2023-12-15T15:13:39.1191439Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" log -1 --format='%H'
2023-12-15T15:13:39.1393070Z 'a8f881856cd1b86888c1bbef5c80686a7893e9ad'
```

Comment: Does that path actually exist? Have you verified it? After abstracting the library out, is it still part of this repo? Please include the directory structure of your repo in your question. Also, instead of adding logs as image, please paste the text in a code block. Thanks!

Comment: The library is not part of the repo so I think that's why, but I don't know how to make the project PART of the repo for GitHub actions to work

Comment: You can make the library a separate repo and then add it as a submodule to your other projects. And, with checkout step of those projects, you'll have to enable submodules as well i.e. `submodules: true`.

Comment: I have edited the question and added submodules and relevant changes to the GitHub actions YAML. The same error. The project can't be found

Comment: Looks like the library is being checkout out properly. Now, you have to check your configuration. Try to build it locally first on the command line. The same configuration should work in your GHA workflow as well.